# Deletar palavra específica de uma string

Tags: php, html, postgresql

Boa noite, pessoal. Estou com um problema que é o seguinte:

Preciso removar a tag '`<br>`' no final dos dados no meu banco de dados (PostgreSQL), devido ao editor de texto que coloca automaticamente.

Não consegui criar nada capaz de fazer isso, mas imagino que eu if que verifica a presença dessa tag e a exclua antes de exibir daria certo (falar é mais fácil que fazer, não é? haha)

Enfim, obrigado desde já!

Comment: O `<br>` so aparece no final?

Comment: Depende, @rray. Esporadicamente poderá haver alguns no meio do texto. Mas o que eu quero remover é esse do final.

Comment: Final do banco? Ou final da "value" de uma coluna especifica?

Comment: o <br> aparece no final de todos os campos de uma tabela, pois inseri esses dados por meio de um editor de texto que coloca esses <br> no final de cada valor, entendeu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você também pode optar por usar esta expressão regular, que faz com que o '
' inserido pelo html,

```
$string = "Texto com linha <br> e linha 2";
$string = str_replace("<br>", "", $string);
```

No MYSQL você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
UPDATE tabela SET campo = REPLACE(campo, '<br>', '');
```

Comment: André, assim como o código do Mateus, é de grande ajuda! Mas como disse, seria interessante remover o 'br' do banco de dados...

Comment: Ok, alterei a resposta

Comment: A resposta é boa, mas convém consertar a expressão usada, pois isso não é uma expressão regular (ainda bem! funções de manipulação de string são preferenciais às expressões regulares). E mais uma sugestão, trocar o `<br>` por espaço, senão a quebra de linha pode "colar" duas palavras indevidamente. (pode-se aplicar um `trim` para tirar os espaços do começo e do fim). De qq forma, +1

Comment: Bacco, como estou trabalhando com variáveis, estou usando a concatenação das variáveis com virgulas, pontos e etc. Deu certinho. Mas ainda espero remover a tag do banco de dados.

Comment: @LéoEduardoSilva a query com UPDATE que o André postou deve resolver a substituição no BD. Se preferir fazer uma alteração não destrutiva para testes, crie uma coluna a mais no banco e use `UPDATE tabela SET campoteste = REPLACE(campo, '<br>', ' ');`. Se ficar contente com os resultados, basta replicar os dados da coluna nova na velha.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Só uma coisa: se eu tiver outra quebra de linha no meio do texto (esta, por sua vez, não quero deletar pois é essencial para o texto) também será apagada?

Comment: Você pode usar também com espaçamento, ai na hora de substituir, ele substitui por espaço. o que resolve também

Comment: Deste modo vai excluir só o último <br>? @AndréBaill

Answer (score 2):

Se entendi direito, você pode resolver isso usando uma expressão regular para tirar o '<br>' desnecessário da string.

```
$texto = "linha 1<br>linha 2<br>";
$texto = preg_replace('(<br>$)', '', $texto);
//remove apenas o <br> do final, mantém os anteriores
```

Comment: Mateus, de fato ajudou. Mas seria interessante remover essa tag do banco de dados. Mas usarei seu código até que consiga fazer isso. Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Não conhecia a função preg_replace :D